# Saving and loading label for first app launch

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I'm using `NSUserDefaults` to save a single label, the label saves and loads perfectly fine except on the apps first launch, so for example when the user downloads the app the label is blank until they start using the app.

Is there a way to load a default abel using `NSUserDefaults` for the app's first launch?

viewDidLoad:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[label setText:[defaults objectForKey:@"myString"]];
```

IBAction:

```
NSUserDefaults *defualts = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *saveString = label.text;
[defualts setObject:saveString forKey:@"myString"];
```

Comment: whats your question ....?

Comment: Update your question with the code that loads the value from `NSUserDefaults` when the app is launched.

Comment: What do you mean by "user downloads the app"

Comment: @SahebRoy for example if its on the app store and you download it the label value will be set to nothing until the user starts to use it, so i want to fill that blank space by saving something inside there for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, the first time the app is run, there is no value in `NSUserDefaults`. Simply update your `viewDidLoad` method like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *title = [defaults objectForKey:@"myString"];
if (!title) {
    title = @"Some Default Title"; // update as needed
}
label.text = title;
```

Comment: Glad I could help. When able, please don't forget to accept the answer to indicate your question has been solved.

Comment: yesi will,  it says i have to wait 2 minutes thats why i haven't yet

Answer (score 0):

if you know what value you want for `myString` then you can set the defaults as part of the package, or when you try to retrieve it, use a default value (or display 'unknown') if the returned value is nil